# Display the date like October 5, 2019 instead of 10/5/2019

Tags: html

I searched until Im exhausted
 I need help with getting the right html codes to display the date format 
October 5, 2019
instead of 10/5/2019
I need the full month name to lead, then a two digit and a four digit
Appreciate any help, as Im creating a cover letter which requires this crisp format.
Regards, Sam

Comment: How are you trying to display the dates? We need to see the code you've got so far.

Comment: Please always show your approach when asking questions here.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your approach of doing this. So, I'm providing one of the simplest way to do it using javascript with HTML.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id = "date"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var d = new Date();
        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
                      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",                      
                      "December"];
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate() + ", " + d.getFullYear();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this which work, but I have to manually type 9 inside the bracket, then it displayed October, I want it to automatically select the current month with out my input

Comment: var today = new Date();
                        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

Comment: var d = new Date();
                        console.log("The current month is " + monthNames[d.getMonth()]);

                        today = monthNames[9] + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
                        document.write(today);

Comment: For date, your approach is right that we need the padding but other than that I think my script also does the same job as yours. In fact mine is pretty simple compared to you. Also, try to run only my script and you will get the response.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it going, many thanks for your input...

```
    <div>
    <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

        var d = new Date();
        console.log("The current month is " + monthNames[d.getMonth()]);

        today = monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + dd + ' ' + yyyy;
        document.write(today);

    </script>
</div>
```